# Why does my posterior mean differs from Idzorek's results?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio, covariance, mean-variance

I have implemented two different expressions ([Idzorek](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/BlackLitterman.pdf) p.6, [Walters](http://www.blacklitterman.org/Black-Litterman.pdf) p.51) of a posterior mean return calculation within a Black-Litterman framework. My results are the same, irrespective of the implemented expression, but if compared to the results published by Idzorek they differ. Also the R package BLCOP returns yet more confusing results. What am I missing?

This is corresponding code...

```
# Equilibrium returns from CAPM, Idzorek p.5
mu = c(0.08, 0.67, 6.41, 4.08, 7.43, 3.70, 4.80, 6.60)/100
assetNames = c("US bonds", "Int bonds", "US large grow", "US large value",
               "US small grow", "US small value", "Int dev EQ", "Int emerg EQ")
# Views (returns and pick matrix), Idzorek p.7, p.13
Q = c(5.25, 0.25, 2)/100 
P = matrix(0, ncol = 8, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, assetNames))
P[1,7] = 1
P[2,1] = -1; P[2,2] <- 1
P[3, 3:6] = c(0.9, -0.9, .1, -.1)
# Prior covariance-variance matrix, Idzorek table 5
entries = c(0.001005,0.001328,-0.000579,-0.000675,0.000121,0.000128,
             -0.000445, -0.000437, 0.001328,0.007277,-0.001307,-0.000610,
             -0.002237,-0.000989,0.001442,-0.001535, -0.000579,-0.001307,
             0.059852,0.027588,0.063497,0.023036,0.032967,0.048039,-0.000675,
             -0.000610,0.027588,0.029609,0.026572,0.021465,0.020697,0.029854,
             0.000121,-0.002237,0.063497,0.026572,0.102488,0.042744,0.039943,
             0.065994 ,0.000128,-0.000989,0.023036,0.021465,0.042744,0.032056,
             0.019881,0.032235 ,-0.000445,0.001442,0.032967,0.020697,0.039943,
             0.019881,0.028355,0.035064 ,-0.000437,-0.001535,0.048039,0.029854,
             0.065994,0.032235,0.035064,0.079958 )
sigma = matrix(entries, ncol = 8, nrow = 8)
# Equilibrium variance uncertainty, Idzorek p. 15
tau = 0.25
omega = diag(c((P[1,]%*%sigma%*%P[1,])*tau, 
               (P[2,]%*%sigma%*%P[2,])*tau, 
               (P[3,]%*%sigma%*%P[3,]))*tau)
# BL master formula for posterior mu in Walters, Appendix E
mu_JWalters = mu+(tau*sigma%*%t(P))%*%inv((tau*P%*%sigma%*%t(P))+omega)%*%(Q-P%*%mu)
# BL master formula for posterior mu in Idzorek p. 6
mu_Idzorek = inv(inv(tau*sigma)+(t(P)%*%inv(omega)%*%P))%*%((inv(tau*sigma)%*%mu)+(t(P)%*%inv(omega)%*%Q))
# BL posterior mu using BLCOP package
views = BLViews(P, Q,confidences=diag(omega), assetNames)
mu_BLCOP = posteriorEst(views=views,mu=mu,tau=tau,sigma=sigma)@posteriorMean
posteriorMuSet = round(cbind(mu_JWalters,mu_Idzorek,mu_BLCOP),digits=4)*100
dimnames(posteriorMuSet) = list(assetNames,c("Walters", "Idzorek", "BLCOP"))
```

... and the result is

```
               Walters Idzorek BLCOP
US bonds          0.05    0.05  0.08
Int bonds         0.32    0.32  0.67
US large grow     6.75    6.75  6.41
US large value    4.51    4.51  4.08
US small grow     7.95    7.95  7.43
US small value    4.15    4.15  3.70
Int dev EQ        5.11    5.11  4.80
Int emerg EQ      7.16    7.16  6.60
```

This is quit different from the actual results in [Idzorek](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/BlackLitterman.pdf). Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Note that I did experiment with different tau values, but even with tau=1 still two asset classes are showing a difference (US bonds and US large grow), even though it's small (0.01%) I am curious as to where it originates from. Also, this would not explain the remarkably different BLCOP result which fails to adjust with changing tau values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To each closure on this: I attribute the difference to Idzorek to rounding errors. And on a side node, Idzorek sets the sample variance equal to the prior variance, an issue that kept myself busy until I found that detail confirmed by Walters paper.

Comment: Oh sure, will do.